# Sorting Graph with Insertion Sort

Tags: java, swing, loops, sorting, timer

I'm trying to sort a bunch of lines in graph step by step to show how different algorithms work with a GUI and timers.

This is what it looks like:

[image: The interface when the program is run]]

I have got the **Bubble sort** to work like this:

```
timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        for (int m = 0; m < tal.length; m++) {
                            for (int n = 0; n < m; n++) {
                                if (tal[n] > tal[n + 1]) {
                                    int temp = tal[n];
                                    tal[n] = tal[n + 1];
                                    tal[n + 1] = temp;
                                    grafPanel.repaint();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
timer.start();
```

However when I try something similar with **Insertion sort**, the whole graph is drawn immediately (not one step at a time like I want it to).

Here is that code:

```
timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        for (int n = 0; n < tal.length; n++) {
                            int temp = tal[n];
                            int i = n - 1;
                            while (i >= 0 && tal[i] > temp) {
                                tal[i + 1] = tal[i];
                                i--;
                            }
                            tal[i + 1] = temp;
                            grafPanel.repaint();

                        }
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
```

This is what the start and final results are(they work fine).
[image: Before the sorting:]
[image: After the sorting:]

Edit:
I understand that I am not actually not inserting the numbers to the array before the full sort is done, then i repaint. I am still not able to fix it though(cant visualize it). More specific help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can see what's wrong. Please also read about [concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), probably this help you to understand what's wrong without our help.

Answer (score 0):

you don't see updates because you don't perform swapping. you're just picking up the proper place for the inserted element (meanwhile shifting elements to the right all along the way), then you insert, and only after that you repaint.

if you do swaps instead (like you did in bubble sort) and repaint after every swap, you would see all necessary updates